# Unit testing sprig data mongodb customer converters

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying unit test spring-data-mongodb custom converter. I am following [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html) document. As per the document there should be a method called afterMappingMongoConverterCreation in AbstractMongoConfiguration class and we need to override that method to configure custom converter. Interestingly that method is not found in the version 1.3.1. (The document is for the same version) The same document also talking about a method named setCustomConverters in MappingMongoConverter. I don't see that method also in MappingMongoConverter or it's super class. Am I missing something here? Any help is much appreciated.

If the document is outdated what is the best way to unit test customer converters? Any option other than XML configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the document is bit outdated. I got it fixed using the below given code.

```
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { ItemRepository.class })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
static class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "scrumretro-test";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() {
        return new Fongo("mongo-test").getMongo();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.scrumretro.repository.mongo";
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
        converters.add(new ItemWriteConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }
}`
```

Comment: customConversions is the new method, which you have to use